# CoreData context saveing bad performance on a big dataset

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have got a big dataset (about 3000 items) of `MoodEntry` objects in CoreData. I have performance issues when adding a new item: animation takes about 2 seconds. Here is the code:

```
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
 @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: MoodEntry.getAllMoodItems()) var moodEntries: FetchedResults<MoodEntry>
```

.

```
Button(action: {
                            
                            let moodEntry = MoodEntry(context: context)
                            moodEntry.value = 1
                            moodEntry.date = Date()
                            moodEntry.id = UUID()
                            
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        
                            let impactLight = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                            impactLight.impactOccurred()

                    }) { Image("Button1").renderingMode(.original) }
```

Does the problem occur because I save all context every time new item is added? Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: If you have added 1 object and not modified anything else then `try context.save()` will only save one object.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the problem occurs because every time moodEntries is updated I have some heavy calculations going under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to execute everything in the background thread?

```
    Button(action: {
                                
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                                let moodEntry = MoodEntry(context: context)
                                moodEntry.value = 1
                                moodEntry.date = Date()
                                moodEntry.id = UUID()
                                
                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
}
                            
                                let impactLight = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                                impactLight.impactOccurred()
    
                        }) { Image("Button1").renderingMode(.original) }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you but didn't help, also I am looking for a solution which will update moodEntries array faster, because I draw realtime charts based on it. I am looking for something like an ability to add 1 item to array without resaving it completely but I don't know is it hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

What animation is slow? I’m guessing you have a List that shows the results of that fetch request, and *that’s* what is slow to update. If so: it’s slow because SwiftUI is diff’ing every row. One workaround is to set .id(UUID()) on the List so the whole thing is regenerated without diffing the rows; here’s an explanation: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui

Comment: Hi! My problem is slow updating of moodEntries array and also I get UIImpactFeedbackGenerator feedback only after some seconds and also button remains tapped (which means darker color) for some seconds.

Comment: I see no reason your database would be slow (3000 isn’t all that big), but UI can be surprisingly slow to update. If your moodEntries array is connected to anything — e.g., a List — that’s almost certainly the problem. The instant you create that new MoodEntry, your moodEntry array will update _and_ trigger a UI update, _before_ the context.save() and feedback generator are even called.